# Internal Server Error after Changing PHP Version in .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5.6

I'm working on laravel version 5.6. My server has application version as following:

> Apache: Apache/2.2.27
>
> PHP: 5.4.27
>
> MySQL: 5.5.59

I don't have access to upgrade PHP version in the server. So, I decided to add this line of code in .htaccess file inside public_html folder.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php
```

So my .htaccess file looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php


# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

but instead of upgrading PHP version, it gives me "500 Internal Server Error" page and downloads a file named 'download'.
What can  I do to deal with this? thank you.

Comment: What is that line `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php` supposed to do? Upgrade to PHP 7?? If you can't upgrade to PHP7 you'll have a hard time working with Laravel 5.6.

Comment: if PHP 7 not installed in your server remove that handler

Comment: @ewwink you mean should I remove `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php` ? so how can I upgrade my php version? I need PHP 7

Comment: @kerbholz yeah, it should upgrade the PHP version, but it doesn't. What should I do?

Comment: Not an expert but that line only tells your server to serve files with the `.php` extension via PHP7. You'd still need to install PHP7 on your server though. Either ask your hoster to upgrade to PHP7 or get another package with PHP7 included.